# Average for each language in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing a school assignment were I need to get the average of each Language entered from a table. I'm struggling to figure it out (For translation: Taal = Language) How do I get the percentage of each language entered in my table?

```
SELECT t.Taal, t.Percentage
FROM (
  SELECT
    Language.Name as Taal, SUM(WatchedMedia.SubtitleID) * COUNT(DISTINCT WatchedMedia.WatchedMediaID) as Percentage,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WatchedMedia.SubtitleID ORDER BY Language.Name DESC) rn    
    FROM WatchedMedia
    INNER JOIN Subtitles ON [WatchedMedia].SubtitleID = Subtitles.SubtitleID
    INNER JOIN Language ON Language.LanguageID = Subtitles.LanguageID 
    WHERE  WatchedMedia.SubtitleID = Subtitles.SubtitleID
    GROUP BY Language.Name, Language.LanguageID, WatchedMedia.SubtitleID
) t
GO
```

This is the result I'm getting now

[image]

These are the entries in table (I replaced Percentage for the number of entries of each language).

The only good percentage I'm getting back is Spanish (sort of). I dont know how to get the correct average of each language entry in my table and converted to percentages.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ties, in which part are you struggling and what is your question?

Comment: why do you need a subquery? You can run everything from your query, no?

Comment: Don't you have the percentage already...? I'm a bit confused on what you are struggling with.

Comment: I need to join my language table to get the name of language.
The flow is a followed. WatchedMedia (Where I want to get my percentages from) -> Subtitles -> Language (Where I want to get the language name from)

Comment: The only correct percentage is Spanish

Comment: can you please put your comments in your question, please?

Comment: [link](https://gyazo.com/c0a4f79f964469908a0751a76a19ba64) These are the entrys of  the subtitles in my WatchedMedia

Comment: [Edit] the question and add the `CREATE` statement of the tables, sample data as `INSERT` statements and the desired result with that sample data as tabular text. Do **not** post screenshots or any other images for that purpose!

Comment: It seems that the WHERE can be eliminated because the InnerJoin ON has the same condition.

Comment: I see now that WHERE is not needed anymore @donPablo

Comment: Show us sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Have you and co-student [Jimmy Habing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62010560/assistance-with-percentage-calculation-in-sql-server) considered pooling your ideas together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Language.Name as Taal,COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(WatchedMedia.WatchedMediaID) FROM WatchedMedia) as Percentage
FROM WatchedMedia
INNER JOIN Subtitles ON [WatchedMedia].SubtitleID = Subtitles.SubtitleID
INNER JOIN Language ON Language.LanguageID = Subtitles.LanguageID 
GROUP BY Language.Name, Language.LanguageID, WatchedMedia.SubtitleID
GO
```

This is what I needed. This solved the problem