# Assistance with Percentage calculation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

DBMS: SQL Server

I am trying to calculate the percentage of how many times a certain language is used for subtitles, for this I tried to retrieve how many times a language is used from my database

The calculation I am trying to do is: `languagesusedforsubtitles / totalamountofsubtitlesused * 100`

My guess is that during my SELECT statement I need to or retrieve the values in a different manner but I can't seem to figure out how.

This is my so far "working" query which displays how many times one language is used for subtitling:

```
-- Sorted language count / total used languages * 100
SELECT DISTINCT [language].name AS "Taal", COUNT(*) AS "Percentage"
FROM [profile]
INNER JOIN [watched_media] ON [watched_media].profileid = [profile].profile_ID
INNER JOIN subtitles ON [watched_media].subtitlesid = [subtitles].subtitles_ID
INNER JOIN language ON [language].language_ID = [subtitles].languageid
GROUP BY [language].name;
```

And this is what I tried in the first place but it only comes up 0's as a result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [language].name AS "Taal", COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(watched_media_ID) FROM [watched_media]) * 100 AS "Hoevaak gebruikt"
FROM [profile]
INNER JOIN [watched_media] ON [watched_media].profileid = [profile].profile_ID
INNER JOIN subtitles ON [watched_media].subtitlesid = [subtitles].subtitles_ID
INNER JOIN language ON [language].language_ID = [subtitles].languageid
GROUP BY [language].name;
```

Here are the results of my first query:

[image: Results image]

Comment: First mistake then :) why have you tagged MySQL?

Comment: Second, please don't use images for code or data, instead format them as text. In this case you have already added your query as text so why take up space with an image?

Comment: Sorry for the MySQL tag :$

Thank you @DaleK I will keep it in mind for next time!

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT, since the GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62010360/average-for-each-language-in-sql-server, same class?

Comment: Thank you very much @jarlh and yes we are in the same class and have been hammering at this for quite a while now

Both designed somewhat different databases and queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does integer division, so `0/1` is `0` rather than `0.5`.  A simple solution for you is:

```
COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(watched_media_ID) FROM [watched_media]
```

The `.0` changes the value from an integer to a decimal number -- and division works more intuitively.